# Extract a substring betwen the closer SPACE and a certain character

Tags: php, substring, extract

As I have to extract the attribute 'inches' from products description, I need a function that extract substring between its closer space recurrence and ".

This is for PHP editor of the WP plugin All-Import.

```
$str = "SIM UMTS ITALIA 15.5" BLACK";
$from = " ";
$to = '"';

function getStringBetween($str,$from,$to){

$sub = substr($str, strpos($str,$from)+strlen($from),strlen($str));
return substr($sub,0,strpos($sub,$to));
}
```

I excpected: 15.5

Results: SIM UMTS ITALIA 15.5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on comments to the answer, this is a preferable solution, as it will return nothing when there is no match to the `$to` string instead of the entire string as the original solution did.

```
function getStringBetween($str,$from,$to){
    if (preg_match("/$from([^$from]+)$to/", $str, $matches))
        return $matches[1];
    else
        return '';
}

$str = 'SIM UMTS ITALIA 35GB BLACK';
echo getStringBetween($str, ' ', 'GB') . "\n";

$str2 = 'SIM UMTS ITALIA IPHONE 2 MEGAPIXEL';
echo getStringBetween($str2, ' ', 'GB') . "\n";

$str3 = 'SIM UMTS ITALIA 15.5" BLACK';
echo getStringBetween($str3, ' ', '"') . "\n";
```

Output:

```
35 

15.5
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/76AbI)

**Original Answer**

It is probably easier to use `preg_replace` instead, looking for some digits or a period before a `"` and removing all other characters from the string e.g.

```
$str = 'SIM UMTS ITALIA 15.5" BLACK';
echo preg_replace('/^.*?(\d+(\.\d+)?)".*$/', '$1', $str);
```

Output:

```
15.5
```

More generically (if `$from` is a character):

```
function getStringBetween($str,$from,$to){
    return preg_replace("/^.*$from([^$from]+)$to.*$/", '$1', $str);
}
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/oesaR)

Comment: Thank you so much.

How can I do the same to for extracting gigabyte, like:
SIM UMTS ITALIA 15.5" 16 GB BLACK

Output: 16

Comment: @Max.P. if you want to extract from a space to `GB`, you can just use `getStringBetween($str,' ', 'GB')` See my updated [demo](https://3v4l.org/SceR8T)

Comment: Hi Nick, It works but if there isn't any 'GB' substring to be matched it exctracts the whole string instead of nothing.

Comment: @Max.P. can you give an example?

Comment: @Max.P. see my edit, I think that will do what you want