# Replace first match using preg_replace

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I need to extract the first occurence of gigabyte attribute from product description.
With my regex preg_rex function it replace last match but I need to replace the first match (only the first).

This is for importing products from CSV files.

```
function getStringBetween($str, $to, $from){

echo preg_replace("/^.*$from([^$from]+)$to.*$/", '$1', $str);

}

$str = 'NGM YOU COLOR P550 DUAL SIM 5.5" IPS HD CURVO QUAD CORE 8GB RAM 1GB 4G LTE';

getStringBetween($str, "GB", " ");
```

From the string: "NGM YOU COLOR P550 DUAL SIM 5.5" IPS HD CURVO QUAD CORE 8GB RAM 1GB 4G LTE"

I expect: 8

It returns 1

Comment: If you use the updated answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54489030/extract-a-substring-betwen-the-closer-space-and-a-certain-character), it will return 8 as you want. https://3v4l.org/QtQcf

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Extract a substring betwen the closer SPACE and a certain character](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54489030/extract-a-substring-betwen-the-closer-space-and-a-certain-character)

Comment: Make the match non greedy `^.*?$from([^$from]+)$to.*$`

Comment: What do you think `[^$from]+` is matching?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In between with regex can be a bit difficult. I recommend using the quantifer `\d+` to specify you're looking specifically for a digit character, and use `preg_match` to fetch the first result:

```
<?php
function getFirstGB($str){

    if (preg_match("/(\d+)GB/", $str, $matches)) {
        return $matches[1];
    } else {
        return false;
    }

}

$str = 'NGM YOU COLOR P550 DUAL SIM 5.5" IPS HD CURVO QUAD CORE 8GB RAM 1GB 4G LTE';

echo getFirstGB($str);
```

PHP Playground [here](https://www.tehplayground.com/Wr5y1KoPEuJTuQ5l).